# Calling Web Service from another one

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jboss

I have got SOAP service implementation with this action in it:

```
public class SimpleWSAction extends AbstractActionPipelineProcessor{

public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleWSAction.class);

private SimpleWSServiceImpl validator = new SimpleWSServiceImpl();
private SimpleWSDAOImpl clientVerificationService = new SimpleWSDAOImpl();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

public SimpleWSAction(ConfigTree _configTree) {
    System.out.println(_configTree.toString());
}

@Process
public Message process(Message message) {   
    if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){ logger.info("SimpleWSAction - START TIME: "+ sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));}
    SimpleWSRequest request = (SimpleWSRequest) message.getBody().get();
    ErrorContainer errorContainer = validator.validateRequest(request);

    if(!errorContainer.checkIfCriticalErrorOccured()){
        clientVerificationService.setPolicyToVerification(prepareDataToVerification(request), errorContainer);
    }
    SimpleWSResponse response = new SimpleWSResponse();

    TechnicalInputEnvelope technicalInputEnvelope = request.getTechnicalInputEnvelope();
    response.setTechnicalOutputEnvelope(getTechnicalOutputEnvelope(technicalInputEnvelope, errorContainer));
    message.getBody().add(response);
    if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){ logger.info("SimpleWSAction - END TIME: "+ sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));}
    return message;
}

}
```

This is the most important part of it i think.

here is my `jboss-esb.xml` im pasting it becouse im wondering if i need it for call 2nd service

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jbossesb parameterReloadSecs="5"
xmlns="http://anonsvn.labs.jboss.com/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.3.0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://anonsvn.labs.jboss.com/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.3.0.xsd http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.3.0.xsd">
<services>
    <service category="SimpleWS"
        description="SimpleWS" invmScope="GLOBAL" name="SimpleWS">
        <security moduleName="SimpleWS"/>
        <property name="maxThreads" value="20" />
        <actions faultXsd="/contract/fault.xsd" inXsd="/contract/request.xsd" 
            mep="RequestResponse" outXsd="/contract/response.xsd">

            <action class="com.ist.esb.error.ErrorServiceAction" name="CAErrorService" process="process" />

            <action class="pl.warta.simplews.actions.JAXBAction" name="XmlToModel" process="fromXml">
                <property name="CLASS" value="pl.warta.simplews.model.request.SimpleWSRequest"/>
            </action>

            <action class="pl.warta.simplews.actions.SimpleWSAction" name="SimpleWSAction" />

            <action class="pl.warta.simplews.actions.JAXBAction"    name="ModelToXml" process="toXml">
                <property name="CLASS" value="pl.warta.simplews.model.response.SimpleWSResponse"/>
            </action>
    </service>
</services>
```

What is more i have got 2nd, similar service. What i want to do is to call the 2nd service called `AdvacedService` (let us assume that it is doing the same job - it is copy of this with changed name of objects etc). How to call it from this service? how about passing request from 1st service as a request for 2nd service or passing some variables? (2nd service is an other project btw)

PS: im sorry for some non-english called variables

i was thinking about calling it like this:

```
String wsdlURL = http://localhost:8080/AdvanceWSService/services/AdvanceWS?wsdl";
String namespace = "http://advancews.com";
String serviceName = "AdvanceWSService";
QName serviceQN = new QName(namespace, serviceName);

ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.newInstance(); 
/* The "new URL(wsdlURL)" parameter is optional */
Service service = serviceFactory.createService(new URL(wsdlURL), serviceQN);
```

but how to pass a request or any parameter in this method?

Comment: Do u want to call it from ur service class or from UI part ?

Comment: from service class for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the JaxWsDynamicClientFactory if you don't intend to provide it with complex types

Also, you technically don't have to import the Person type into the client. All you really need do is be aware of the type and use reflection to generate an instance of the class at runtime.

The version of createClient you've used here is only good for webservice operations that accept simple types. To be able to pass a complex type to a dynamic webservice client,

JaxWsDynamicClientFactory needs to dynamically generate the necessary support classes with the following:

```
ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient("wsdlPath", classLoader);
```

This creates the Client object and also the necessary pojos.

Then you'll be able to call the service with:

//Dynamically load an instance of the Model class. You're not importing and you can simply configure the class name as an application property

```
Object model = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("foo.bar.Model").newInstance(); 
Method theMethod = person.getClass().getMethod("setAge", Integer.class);
theMethod.invoke(person, 55); //set a property

client.invoke("testPerson", model); //invoke the operation.
```

**You can try this out for passing parameter :**

```
  import javax.xml.rpc.Call;
    import javax.xml.rpc.Service;
    import javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException;
    import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
    import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory;
    import javax.xml.rpc.ParameterMode;

    public class DIIHello {

        private static String qnameService = "MyHelloService";
        private static String qnamePort = "MyHelloServiceRPC";
        private static String endpoint =
            "http://localhost:80/MyHelloService/MyHelloService";

        private static String BODY_NAMESPACE_VALUE =
            "urn:MyHelloService/wsdl";
        private static String ENCODING_STYLE_PROPERTY =
            "javax.xml.rpc.encodingstyle.namespace.uri";
        private static String NS_XSD =
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        private static String URI_ENCODING =
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {

                ServiceFactory factory =
                    ServiceFactory.newInstance();
                Service service =
                    factory.createService(new QName(qnameService));

                QName port = new QName(qnamePort);

                Call call = service.createCall(port);
                call.setTargetEndpointAddress(endpoint);

                call.setProperty(Call.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY,
                    new Boolean(true));
                call.setProperty(Call.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "");
                call.setProperty(ENCODING_STYLE_PROPERTY,
                    URI_ENCODING);
                QName QNAME_TYPE_STRING = new QName(NS_XSD, "string");
                call.setReturnType(QNAME_TYPE_STRING);


                call.setOperationName(new QName(BODY_NAMESPACE_VALUE,
                    "sayHello"));
                 //For passing parameter
                call.addParameter("String_1", QNAME_TYPE_STRING,
                    ParameterMode.IN);
                String[] params = { "Kuntal" };

                String result = (String)call.invoke(params);
                System.out.println(result);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try it asap and let u know how its working